# No form validation in my angular app

Tags: angularjs, validation, forms

I tried and searched a lot, but no solution. The form validation in my angular app still not working.

I tried for example:

```html
 <form data-ng-controller="ValidationController" name="validationForm" novalidate="novalidate">
 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="username">Mail</label>
   <input name="username" 
    type="email" 
    data-ng-model="formData.username"
    required="required">
   <span ng-show="form.username.$invalid">Invalid mail address</span>
  </div> 
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="formData.$invalid">Submit</button>
 
  <pre>
   <tt>formData = {{formData}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>formData.$valid = {{formData.$valid}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>formData.username.$valid = {{formData.username.$valid}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>formData.username.$error = {{formData.username.$error}}</tt><br/>
   <hr>
 
  </pre>
  
 </form>
```

Another one I tried:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="large-12 columns">
  <label>Your email</label> <input type="email" placeholder="Email"
   name="email" ng-model="signup.email" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20
   required />
  <div class="error-container"
   ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid">
   <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.required">
    Your email is required. </small> <small class="error"
    ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.minlength"> Your email is required
    to be at least 3 characters </small> <small class="error"
    ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.email"> That is not a valid email.
    Please input a valid email. </small> <small class="error"
    ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.maxlength"> Your email cannot be
    longer than 20 characters </small>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But the validation does not work. If I have to enable the validation? But for this I also didn't find anything. It seems, that validation is still enabled in Angular. But why it does not work in my app? All other things works fine.

Regards
Bytecounter

Comment: You should post all your code for help. You need to reference the form not the model itself. try`validationForm.$invalid` and `validationForm.username.$valid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form data-ng-controller="ValidationController" name="validationForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Mail</label>
        <input name="username" 
            type="email" 
            data-ng-model="username"
            required>
        <span ng-show="validationForm.username.$invalid && validationForm.username.$dirty">Invalid mail address</span>
    </div>  

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-disabled="formData.$invalid">Submit</button>

    <pre>
        <tt>formData = {{validationForm}}</tt><br/>
        <tt>formData.$valid = {{validationForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
        <tt>formData.username.$valid = {{validationForm.username.$valid}}</tt><br/>
        <tt>formData.username.$error = {{validationForm.username.$error}}</tt><br/>
        <hr>    
    </pre>      
</form>
```

Actually your form is available by its name.
Check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uJPqgnPEUMNTGxZdRkaL?p=preview).

Comment: Thank's a lot! That was the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors there.

#### First:

```
ng-show="form.username.$invalid"
```

You are referencing a variable `form` that does not exist in your scope. You should reference `validationForm`:

```
ng-show="validationForm.username.$invalid"
```

#### Second:

```
data-ng-disabled="formData.$invalid"
```

You are referencing the `model` of the input, instead of it's form object, that is, again, `validationForm`:

```
data-ng-disabled="validationForm.$invalid"
```

That should do.